# C++ Destructor is not being called/Object is not being deleted - Potential Memory Leak

Tags: c++, memory, memory-leaks, constructor, destructor

My first question is: I am having a lot of trouble figuring out why the Example class is being constructed greater than the others. Below is a short app using a Template counter to track how many times the constructor/destructor/copy constructor is called for each class. There are a total of three classes: Example, Deep, Child. Each has a copy constructor... ugh.

Also, my second question, is what would be the correct way to define the copy constructor for the Child class?

In the printStatus(), it displays:

```
COUNTERS::NEW_COUNTER = 60
COUNTERS::DELETE_COUNTER = 50
COUNTERS::CONSTRUCTOR_COUNTER = 90
COUNTERS::DESTRUCTOR_COUNTER = 80
Example count = 10
Deep count = 0
Child count = 0
```

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class COUNTERS
{
    public:
        static int NEW_COUNTER;
        static int DELETE_COUNTER;
        static int CONSTRUCTOR_COUNTER;
        static int DESTRUCTOR_COUNTER;  
};

int COUNTERS::NEW_COUNTER = 0;
int COUNTERS::DELETE_COUNTER = 0;
int COUNTERS::CONSTRUCTOR_COUNTER = 0;
int COUNTERS::DESTRUCTOR_COUNTER = 0;

/* template used for counting constructors/destructors to debug memory leaks */
template <typename T>
class Countable
{
    static unsigned cs_count_;
public:
    Countable() { ++cs_count_; }
    Countable( Countable const& ) { ++cs_count_; }
    virtual ~Countable() { --cs_count_;}
    static unsigned count() { return cs_count_; }
};

template <typename T>
unsigned Countable<T>::cs_count_ = 0;
```

---

```
class Example : public Countable<Example>
{
    public:
        string a;
        int b;

        Example()        {
            COUNTERS::CONSTRUCTOR_COUNTER++;

            a = "exampleString";
            b = 5;
        }

        virtual ~Example()        {
            COUNTERS::DESTRUCTOR_COUNTER++;
        }

        // copy constructor
        Example(const Example& e)        {
            COUNTERS::CONSTRUCTOR_COUNTER++;

            this->a = e.a;
            this->b = e.b;
        }
};
```

---

```
class Deep  : public Countable<Deep>
{
    public:
        int a;
        string b; 
        Example* e;

        Deep()      
        {
            COUNTERS::CONSTRUCTOR_COUNTER++;

            a = 3;
            b = "deepString";
            e = new Example();
            COUNTERS::NEW_COUNTER++;
        }

        virtual ~Deep()     {
            if(e != NULL)           {
                delete e;
                COUNTERS::DELETE_COUNTER++;
            }
            COUNTERS::DESTRUCTOR_COUNTER++;
        }

        // copy constructor
        Deep(const Deep& x)
        {
            COUNTERS::CONSTRUCTOR_COUNTER++;

            this->a = x.a;
            this->b = x.b;

            this->e = new Example(); 
            COUNTERS::NEW_COUNTER++;

            this->e->a = x.e->a;
            this->e->b = x.e->b;
        };
};
```

---

```
class Child  : public Countable<Child>
{
    public:
        Deep d;
        string name;
        int age;
        Example* e;

        vector<Example> list;
        vector<Deep> deep_list;

        void init()
        {
            Deep* var = new Deep(); COUNTERS::NEW_COUNTER++;
            deep_list.push_back(*var);
            delete var; COUNTERS::DELETE_COUNTER++;
        }

        Child() {
            COUNTERS::CONSTRUCTOR_COUNTER++;

            name = "a";
            age = 10;
            d.a = 1;
            d.b = "deep";
            d.e = NULL;

            e = new Example();
            COUNTERS::NEW_COUNTER++;

            list.push_back(*e);

            init();
        }

        virtual ~Child()        {
            COUNTERS::DESTRUCTOR_COUNTER++;
            if(e != NULL)           {
                delete e;
                COUNTERS::DELETE_COUNTER++;
            }
        }

        // copy constructor
        Child(const Child& c)
        {

        }
};

void myChildFunction(){
    Child* c = new Child();
    COUNTERS::NEW_COUNTER++;

    delete c;
    COUNTERS::DELETE_COUNTER++;
}

void printStatus(){
    cout << "COUNTERS::NEW_COUNTER = " << COUNTERS::NEW_COUNTER << endl;
    cout << "COUNTERS::DELETE_COUNTER = " << COUNTERS::DELETE_COUNTER << endl;
    cout << "COUNTERS::CONSTRUCTOR_COUNTER = " << COUNTERS::CONSTRUCTOR_COUNTER << endl;
    cout << "COUNTERS::DESTRUCTOR_COUNTER = " << COUNTERS::DESTRUCTOR_COUNTER << endl;

    cout << "Example count = " << Example::count() << endl;
    cout << "Deep count = " << Deep::count() << endl;
    cout << "Child count = " << Child::count() << endl;
}
```

---

```
int main() 
{
    for(unsigned int i=0 ; i < 10; i++) 
        myChildFunction();  

    printStatus();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you already step through with a debugger, to get a grip what your code actually does?

Comment: Are you asking us to debug your code? Why don't you do this yourself?

Comment: Sorry. Yes, I had used print statements in this snippet of code before, but it seems Each class seems to be destroying its' resources correctly. Inside the Child class, there is a deep_list vector. I learned that objects are copied into the vector. So I created a copy constructor for the Deep class since there is a deep_list inside the Child class. Inside Deep contains a pointer to an Example object. The Deep copy constructor creates a new Example object. And I suspect the problem might be there, but I can't find out what the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing out on deleting some `Example` objects because of this line:

```
     d.e = NULL;
```

in `Child::Child()`.

You are allocating memory for `e` in the constructor of `Deep`. After executing the above line, that memory is leaked.

You can resolve that problem by:

1. Removing that line (or commenting it out),
2. Deleting `d.e` before making it NULL, or
3. Doing something else that prevents the memory leak.

**Update, in response to comment**

Copy constructor for `Child`:

```
  Child(const Child& c) : d(c.d),
                          name(c.name),
                          age(c.age),
                          e(new Example(*c.e)),
                          list(c.list),
                          deep_list(c.deep_list)
  {
     COUNTERS::DESTRUCTOR_COUNTER++; // This is for Child
     COUNTERS::NEW_COUNTER++;        // This is for new Example   
  }
```

Comment: Thank you so much R, Sahu. Ugh I knew it was something like that. May I ask, how did you debug that? Did you visually just see that or did you run a debugger to find that? Also, could you advise on the best way to define the Child(const Const& c) copy constructor?

Comment: @user1456962, you are welcome. Divide and conquer. Take out lines of code until the problem is identified.

Comment: in this sample, there is no need to make `Example` a pointer anyways

Comment: @R Sahu , what is the best way to define the Child(const Const& c) copy constructor?

Answer (score 1):

I removed all information that cluttered your code. 
When using templates, constructors and copy constructors NEED the following: Example < eltType >(void);
in the class definition. All objects that inherit from Countables are known as derived classes. They also may call a derived class a child, and the class in which it is derived from is called the parent. I added the COPY_CONSTRUCTOR_COUNT to add clarification to the data which is being presented on the console/command prompt. Usually when trying to preform a task, large or small, doing it incrementally and by providing methods, for each task, saves you time and a headache. I removed the new_count and delete_count from the equation, because I felt that it was not needed.

You will notice that I added : Countable( * ((Countable < eltType > *)&e))
This is a requirement when designing a program that involves inheritance, which introduces the 
topic of Polymorphism :D

What that bit of code does is that it gets a pointer of a Countable, which will point to the address of object e, which then allows access to all super classes of this class, but not including e's class.

NOTE: Since e is a derived class of Countable, this is valid statement.

For you second question, all of your data members are public, you can use an iterator to copy your data stored in you vectors.

As a concern from one programmer to another, I hope your code in practice is well documented, and all methods declared in your class are defined in a .cpp file.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class COUNTERS
{
public:
static int NEW_COUNTER;
static int DELETE_COUNTER;
static int CONSTRUCTOR_COUNTER;
static int DESTRUCTOR_COUNTER;
static int COPY_CONSTRUCTOR_COUNTER;
};

int COUNTERS::NEW_COUNTER = 0;
int COUNTERS::DELETE_COUNTER = 0;
int COUNTERS::CONSTRUCTOR_COUNTER = 0;
int COUNTERS::DESTRUCTOR_COUNTER = 0;
int COUNTERS::COPY_CONSTRUCTOR_COUNTER = 0;

/* template used for counting constructors/destructors to debug memory leaks */
template <typename T>
class Countable
{
public:
Countable<T>() 
{ 
    incrementObjectCount(); 
};

Countable<T>(Countable const&) 
{ 
    incrementObjectCount(); 
};

virtual ~Countable() 
{
    decrementObjectCount(); 
};

static unsigned count() 
{ 
    return cs_count_; 
};

protected:
static unsigned cs_count_;

////////////////////////////////////ADDED////////////////////////////////////
protected:
void incrementObjectCount(void){ ++cs_count_; };
void decrementObjectCount(void){ --cs_count_; };
void incrementDeconstructorCounter(void){ ++COUNTERS::DESTRUCTOR_COUNTER; };
/////////////////////////////////////ADDED////////////////////////////////////
};

template <typename T>
unsigned Countable<T>::cs_count_ = 0;

class Example : public Countable<Example>
{
public:


Example() : Countable<Example>() 
{
    COUNTERS::CONSTRUCTOR_COUNTER++;
}

virtual ~Example()        
{
    incrementDeconstructorCounter();
}

// copy constructor
Example(const Example& e) : Countable<Example>(*((Countable<Example>*)&e))
{
    // COUNTERS::CONSTRUCTOR_COUNTER++; This is copy constructor, you addmitted this from     "Child"     class CCstr
    ++COUNTERS::COPY_CONSTRUCTOR_COUNTER; // For even more information added this
}
};

class Deep : public Countable<Deep>
{
public:

Deep() : Countable<Deep>()
{
    COUNTERS::CONSTRUCTOR_COUNTER++;
}

virtual ~Deep()     
{
    COUNTERS::DESTRUCTOR_COUNTER++;
}

// copy constructor
Deep(const Deep& x) : Countable<Deep>(*((Countable<Deep>*)&x))
{
    //COUNTERS::CONSTRUCTOR_COUNTER++;
    ++COUNTERS::COPY_CONSTRUCTOR_COUNTER; // For even more information added this
};
};


class Child : public Countable<Child>
{
public:

vector<Example> list;
vector<Deep> deep_list;

void init()
{
    deep_list.push_back(Deep()); 
    list.push_back(Example());
}

Child() : Countable<Child>() 
{
    COUNTERS::CONSTRUCTOR_COUNTER++;
    init();
}

virtual ~Child()        
{
    COUNTERS::DESTRUCTOR_COUNTER++;
}

// copy constructor
Child(const Child& c) : Countable<Child>(*((Countable<Child>*)&c))
{
    ++COUNTERS::COPY_CONSTRUCTOR_COUNTER; // For even more information added this
}
};

void myChildFunction(){
Child* c = new Child();
//COUNTERS::NEW_COUNTER++;not needed

delete c;
//COUNTERS::DELETE_COUNTER++; not need
}

void printStatus(){



cout << "COUNTERS::NEW_COUNTER = " << COUNTERS::NEW_COUNTER << endl;
cout << "COUNTERS::DELETE_COUNTER = " << COUNTERS::DELETE_COUNTER << endl;
cout << "COUNTERS::CONSTRUCTOR_COUNTER = " << COUNTERS::CONSTRUCTOR_COUNTER << endl;
cout << "COUNTERS::DESTRUCTOR_COUNTER = " << COUNTERS::DESTRUCTOR_COUNTER << endl;
cout << "COUNTERS::COPY_CONSTRUCTOR_COUNTER = " << COUNTERS::COPY_CONSTRUCTOR_COUNTER << endl;

cout << "Example count = " << Example::count() << endl;
cout << "Deep count = " << Deep::count() << endl;
cout << "Child count = " << Child::count() << endl;
}

int main()
{
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    myChildFunction();

printStatus();
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```